# how to get the timestamp of images inside a folder in firebase storage?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I want to make a cron job using cloud function, this cron job will delete images that has been stored for more than 6 months in folder `eventPoster`. but the problem is, I don't know how to get the timestamp of all images inside of a folder, so I can't compare to current timestamp.

this is the folders structure
[image]

so I want to get all images inside `eventPoster` folder and then check the timestamp when that image is created. how to do that ?

```
const storage = admin.storage()
const defaultBucket = storage.bucket()
```

Comment: You will need to combine the results of the [list API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects) at the desired prefix, along with a check of the file [metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata) for each file.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you. after I get the files, I can't find timestamp metadata on list of the link you provide to access when the the image created